# Get name of all Nodes in a XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I need a little help.
I need the names from all nodes who have text in a xml in js.

example:

```
<xml>
  <first>
    <name1>text</name1>
  </first>
  <second>
    <name2>text</name2>
    <name3>text</name3>
  </second>
</xml>
```

now i need as result:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

thx

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the earlier answer as I didn't realise you wanted any text and not just "text". Using document.createTreeWalker() seems to be a pure javascript effective solution for any node that has any text and should fit your needs perfectly.

```
var treeWalker=document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
treeWalker.firstChild(); 
while (treeWalker.nextSibling())
    { 
       text=treeWalker.currentNode;
       if (text.nodeValue!=false)
       {
            alert(text.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()); 
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`$.parseXML();`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```js
var xmlStr = "<xml><first><name1>text</name1></first><second><name2>text</name2><name3>text</name3></second></xml>";
var xml = $($.parseXML(xmlStr)); // parse the string to make xml and covert to jQuery obj
xml.find("*").filter(function(){ 
    return this.nodeName.indexOf("name") == 0; // filter only elements starting with name
}).each(function(){
    console.log(this.nodeName); // log the name
});
```

`xmlStr` can be either direct string or from an ajax call.

Comment: hey thx. sry my fault.
the <name> tag can have every name i dont know.
<xml>
  <first>
    <dog>text</dog>
  </first>
  <second>
    <cat>text</cat>
    <house>text</house>
  </second>
</xml>